# how to write into .txt file in R?

Tags: r, file

I have a data that looks like this.For example:

```
 A;a 
 B;a 
 C;b 
 D;c
 A;b
 A;d
 C;c 
 ....
```

First pos = key , second pos = value. If key; value , then 1 ,if not then 0;

I would to create binary matrix from data.

```
   a b c d
 A 1 1 0 1  
 B 1 0 0 0
 C 0 1 1 0
 D 0 0 0 1
```

I could create matrix, my code:

```
KeyandValue = read.table('~/RStudioProjects/TestData.txt',sep=';',header = FALSE)

tableForData <- table(KeyandValue$V1,KeyandValue$V2)
tableForData[tableForData > 1] <- 1

 csvFile<- write.table(tableForData,file = 
  "~/RStudioProjects/TestData.csv",quote = F,sep = ";")
  write.csv(csvFile)
```

Now, i want to re-write to .txt format in this form:

```
A;a;1
A;b;1
A;c;0
A;d;1
B;a;1
B;b;0
B;c;0
B;d;0   
.....
```

My code:

```
t3<-tableForData[,]
View(t3)
```

then i view table in this form 
 [image]

How i can write in this form into .txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(edited for better consistency with the OP)

In base R you can do it in just one line using `as.data.frame.table`:

```
df <- data.frame(
         V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "C"), 
         V2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d", "c"))
tableForData <- with(df, table(V1,V2))
tableForData[tableForData > 1] <- 1
t3 <- as.data.frame(tableForData)  #this is the working part :)
```

Then **t3** is...

```
> head(t3)
  V1 V2 Freq
1 A a    1
2 B a    1
3 C a    0
4 D a    0
5 A b    1
6 B b    0
```

You can sort it if the order of rows is important:

```
t3 <- t3[order(t3$V1),]
```

... and write into a file:

```
write.table(t3, "afilename.csv", sep=";", col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: when i try write into file  , write.table(t3,file = "~/Data.txt",quote = F,col.names = F,row.names = F)    I get result                                            1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1

Comment: well you must have done something differently then ... in my computer, the result is as expected ... but you should add `sep=";"` to write.table

Comment: using your code from above, i.e. `tableForData` you created, the one-line result would be: `write.table(as.data.frame(tableForData), "afilename.csv", quote=F, sep=";", col.names=F, row.names=F)`. This is sorted differently though, if order is important, you need to sort it first.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table("id" = c("A","B","C","D"),
                 "a" = c(1,1,0,0),
                 "b" = c(1,0,1,0),
                 "c" = c(0,0,1,0),
                 "d" = c(1,0,0,1))

dt_m <- melt.data.table(dt,id.vars = "id")

write.table(dt_m,"test.txt", sep=";",col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

**Edit after  @MichaelChirico suggestion**

Instead of

`write.table(dt_m,"test.txt", sep=";",col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

it is better to use

`fwrite(dt_m,"test.txt", sep=";",col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico you are right. incorporated your comment to my answer. Thank you

Comment: But i have the big data(line and rows ), my data don't have line name that  "id","a","b", etc.. How i set name(id) first line ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reshape2::melt` to reshape the data into the form you want, then save the table without row or column names.

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(1:4, function(i) sample(1:0, 4, replace=TRUE)))
colnames(df) <- letters[1:4]
rownames(df) <- LETTERS[1:4]
#> df
#
#  a b c d
#A 1 0 1 0
#B 1 1 1 0
#C 1 0 1 1
#D 1 0 0 1

## Saving to disk
df$id <- rownames(df)
write.table(reshape2::melt(df), sep=";", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A third option would be to use tidyr

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

long_data = data.frame(X1=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), X2=c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

long_data %>% 
  spread(X1, 1) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-X2), funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0, 1))) %>%
  column_to_rownames("X2") %>%
  write.table(file="TestData.csv", quote=F, sep=";")
#   A;B;C;D
# a;1;0;0;0
# b:0;1;0;0
# c;0;0;1;0
# d;0;0;0;1

expand.grid(long_data) %>%
  left_join(long_data %>% mutate(val=1)) %>%
  replace_na(list(val=0)) %>%
  write.table(file="TestData2.csv", quote=F, sep=";")
# X1;X2;val
# A;a;1
# B;a;0
# C;a;0
# D;a;0
# A;b;0
# B;b;1
# C;b;0
# D;b;0
# A;c;0
# B;c;0
# C;c;1
# D;c;0
# A;d;0
# B;d;0
# C;d;0
# D;d;1
```